# "Quotient" as a verb

Tags: terminology, quotient-spaces

People here do use "quotient" as a verb: I searched for "quotienting" and got 12,890 results. [**Edit:** It's not as bad as I thought. Apparently I didn't understand how the search function works. When I put quotation marks around the search term I get only 207 results for "quotienting" and 64 for "quotiented".]

1. Why do they do this? Is it just that they want to be ungrammatical, perhaps for humorous effect? Or is there some actual confusion or ambiguity which could result from using a normal verb like "divide"?
2. Is the verb "to quotient" just a kind of academic slang which you can get away with only in a informal setting such as this web site or a classroom? Or is it accepted even by high class publications like the Annals of Mathematics or the AMS or LMS journals?

Comment: Maybe (more) suited for http://english.stackexchange.com/ ? I personally have never used "to quotient" in my life (but possibly "to mod out" or similar), but then I'm no native speaker.

Comment: People are just verbing the word "quotient".

Comment: I’m with @Hagen (and I am a native speaker): for me it’s *to mod out (by)* or, if I’m being more formal, *take/form the quotient (by)*.

Comment: @James Yeah, of course the word class barrier is incredibly low in English

Comment: I agree with Hagen von Eitzen that this is more a question about the english language than maths. It is not uncommon in english to create new verbs from nouns which just mean, "I am doing *noun*". For example "googling". The question of whether or not it is correct should be asked to a linguist, or english teacher.

Comment: @Hagamena No, it's a question about *mathematical* English, which a normal English teacher or linguist would know nothing about.

Comment: The English language is quite self-explanatory. When we can "dot" two vectors why not "quotient" a number by another one ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is standard mathematical terminology in the context of [quotient spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_space_(linear_algebra)) and [quotient groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_group).  The use of "divide" or "division" is nonstandard and generally considered incorrect in these contexts.

One reason a new word is needed is if, for example, the group operation is addition.  Then the quotient group of $G$ by subgroup $N$, written $G/N$, consists of elements $N+g$, for various $g\in G$.  There is no dividing going on.

Comment: G/N was at some point called the difference group, and written $G-N$.

Comment: Maybe I missed one, but I couldn't find one instance of "quotient" as a verb in either of the linked Wikipedia pages. I don't see why a new word is needed, when "take the quotient" seems to do the job. Well, all right, so now "quotient" is a verb. If wonder if the newer Bibles have God say "be fruitful and product"?

Comment: This answer has "quotient by": https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4556720/is-this-monster-related-coincidence-actually-a-coincidence