# Show a homomorphism exists iff there exist homomorphisms from each finitely generated substructure

Tags: logic, model-theory

Let $\mathcal{L}$ be a signature (or language), and let $\mathcal{A}$ be a finite $\mathcal{L}$-model (or $\mathcal{L}$-structure). Show that there is a homomorphism from an $\mathcal{L}$-model $\mathcal{B}$ into $\mathcal{A}$ if and only if there are homomorphisms from each finitely generated substructure of $\mathcal{B}$ into $\mathcal{A}$.

Here's what I have so far: I think the "$\Rightarrow$" direction is simple, as you can just take the given homomorphism restricted to the substructure; this should still be a homomorphism.

I initially thought the "$\Leftarrow$" was trivial as well, as you can just take $\mathcal{B}$ as one of the finitely generated substructures. But then I realised that $\mathcal{B}$ may not be finitely generated from a substructure (is that possible?). I feel like I might have to use compactness or ultraproducts (given the phrase "finitely generated substructure"), but I'm not really sure how.

Apologies if what I'm saying doesn't make sense, I'm still trying to get a grasp of model theory. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I think instead of "into" you should be saying "to" - "into" suggests injectivity, and the only structures that inject into finite structures are finite.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I never knew that "into" suggests injectivity.

Comment: @bof It's not universal (and may not even be widespread?), but I've definitely been cautioned against using "into" in papers when the function I'm talking about isn't injective.

Comment: @bof Here's an example: http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/52454.html. I think using "into" for "injective" is bad practice, but it's widespread enough that it's better to avoid it.

Comment: @NoahSchweber "Consider two sets $A$ and $B$, whose elements may be any objects whatsoever, and suppose that with each element $x$ of $A$ there is associated, in some manner, an element of $B,$ which we denote by $f(x).$ Then $f$ is said to be a *function* from $A$ to $B$ (or a *mapping* of $A$ into $B$). [, , , .] If $f(A)=B,$ we say that $f$ maps $A$ *onto* $B.$ (Note that, according to this usage, *onto* is more specific than *into*.)" — Walter Rudin, *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*, Third Edition, p. 24.

Comment: The idea that "into" implies injectivity is just plain **wrong** and should be utterly disregarded.

Comment: I've never heard of "into" implying injectivity, but I guess it doesn't hurt to avoid it

Comment: @bof Look, we agree that "into" is not a synonym of "injective". All I'm saying is that a lot of people believe that it is, so it's best to avoid confusion by not using it. Citing a single source, however reputable, isn't good evidence that another usage isn't widespread (albeit in less reputable sources). Plus, there's a convenient alternative to "into" that has the advantage of being two characters shorter!

Comment: @AlexKruckman The problem with catering to the ignorant notion that "into" implies injectivity, instead of trying to stamp it out, is that we will be reading papers and books where the authors don't think they have to tell us that they're assuming some map is injective, because they have used the preposition "into".

Comment: @bof In my opinion, the best practice is to avoid (and encourage others to avoid) *any* potentially ambiguous use of language in mathematics, regardless of which usage is "right" or "wrong". But then, I (and many in my mathematical communities) regularly use the word ["quotient" as a verb](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1259494/quotient-as-a-verb) without thinking twice, so it's safe to assume you and I have different linguistic standards!

Comment: @AlexKruckman I'm all for avoiding ambiguity. Lots of ambiguities, like whether $\subset$ means "subset" or "proper subset", are too well established to do anything about them, so I'm forced to write $\subseteq$ when I mean "subset" and $\subsetneq$ when I mean "proper subset". Whoever is responsible for this "into means injective" foolishness has just created a source of vast ambiguity where there was none before, instantly rendering thousands of books and papers ambiguous, or changing their meaning. Since I never heard of it before today, I'm hoping it hasn't metastasized yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose the operations and relations of $L$ are finitary. Let $A$ and $B$ be the underlying sets of $\mathcal A$ and $\mathcal B.$ Let $[B]^{\lt\omega}$ be the set of all finite subsets of $B.$ Let $\mathcal U$ be an ultrafilter on $[B]^{\lt\omega}$ such that $\{X\in[B]^{\lt\omega}:b\in X\}\in\mathcal U$ for each $b\in B.$

For each $X\in[B]^{\lt\omega}$ choose a homomorphism $f_X:\langle X\rangle\to\mathcal A,$ where $\langle X\rangle$ is the substructure of $\mathcal B$ generated by $X.$ For each $b\in B,$ define $f(b)$ as the unique element $a\in A$ such that $f_X(b)=a$ for $\mathcal U$-almost all $X\in[B]^{\lt\omega},$ that is, $\{X\in[B]^{\lt\omega}:f_X(b)=a\}\in\mathcal U.$ (Such an element $a$ exists because $A$ is finite, and because of the special property of the ultrafilter $\mathcal U$ which guarantees that $f_X(b)$ is defined for $\mathcal U$-almost all $X.$) This function $f:\mathcal B\to\mathcal A$ is a homomorphism.

To see that $f$ is a homomorphism, observe that, if $k\lt\omega$ and $b_1,\dots,b_k\in B,$ then $f|\{b_1,\dots,b_k\}=f_X|\{b_1,\dots,b_k\}$ for some (in fact for almost all) $X\in[B]^{\lt\omega}.$

**Example:** If $\mathcal B$ is a (simple, undirected, not necessarily finite) graph, and if $\mathcal A=K_n$ (the complete graph of order $n$) for some natural $n,$ then a homomorphism of the graph $\mathcal B$ into $\mathcal A$ is just a proper $n$-coloring of the vertices of $\mathcal B.$ In this case we have the [De Bruijn–Erdős theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn%E2%80%93Erd%C5%91s_theorem_(graph_theory)) which says that a graph is $n$-colorable iff every finite subgraph is $n$-colorable.

Comment: Very nice answer, by the way!